# Is is safe to call getResource on class object during static initialization?

Tags: java, static, resources

Snippet:

```
class MyClass {
    static {
        var resource = MyClass.class.getResource("something");
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it safe to use `MyClass.class` and its `getResource` method during static initialization?

Comment: Yes. And it’s very common to read a resource during initialization.